# Caption options don't work in rmarkdown beamer template

Tags: beamer, captions, knitr, markdown, rstudio

I want to resize the figure captions in an rmarkdown beamer template, so I added `\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}` to my `header.tex`. But it doesn't work - the options are ignored. I didn't find any similar problem so far. Any ideas? thank you.

.rmd file:

```
---
title: "Presentation"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
      fig_caption: true
---
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{image.jpg}
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\end{figure}
```

header.tex:

```
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{%
\begin{textblock*}{25mm}(10cm,0.5cm)
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{logo.png}
\end{textblock*}
}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{25mm}(10cm,0.5cm)
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{logo.png}
\end{textblock*}}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt} Institute | Hans Dampf \hfill\insertshortauthor\hfill\insertpagenumber}}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```

Comment: Please give us a small but complete document which shows the problem and which we can compile (MWE). Having only code snippets we cannot reproduce your problem and therefore it's difficult to help.

Answer (score 2):

`beamer` and the `caption` package are not the best friends, but you can simply use `beamer`s font mechanism to control the caption size:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny, shape=\itshape}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `shape=\itshape` in the definition of the `caption` font?